# Getting Segmentation Fault While Trying To Call A Custom Memory Management Library Function From A Different File

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

For a course project, I am trying to create a custom library that includes some functions about memory management. And I need to use the functions of this library in different files. However, I encountered strange errors. When I run them inside the main function of smemlib.c, my functions are working well. But when I trying to invoke them in create_memory.c, I get segmentation fault.

**Here is the related part of smemlib.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int smem_init(int segsize)
{
    //Check if input is power of two
     printf("Test\n");
    if (segsize && !(segsize&(segsize-1))){
        printf("Power of 2\n");
    }
    else 
        return -1;   
}

int main()
{
    int i, ret; 
    char *p; 
    i  = smem_init(4096);
    printf("i value is %d\n", i);
}
```

**And here is the create_memory.c :**

```
#include "smemlib.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{   
    int i= smem_init(4096); 
    if (-1 == i)
        return (0);
    printf ("memory segment is removed from the system. System is clean now.\n");
    printf ("you can no longer run processes to allocate memory using the library\n"); 

    return (0); 
}
```

**And my makefile:**

```
all: libsmemlib.a  app create_memory destroy_memory smemlib

libsmemlib.a:  smemlib.c
    gcc -Wall -c smemlib.c
    ar -cvq libsmemlib.a smemlib.o
    ranlib libsmemlib.a

app: app.c
    gcc -Wall -o app app.c -L. -lsmemlib -lpthread -lrt

smemlib: smemlib.c
    gcc -Wall -o smemlib smemlib.c -lpthread -lrt

create_memory: create_memory.c
    gcc -Wall -o create_memory create_memory.c -L. -lsmemlib -lpthread -lrt

destroy_memory: destroy_memory.c
    gcc -Wall -o destroy_memory destroy_memory.c -L. -lsmemlib -lpthread -lrt 

clean: 
    rm -fr *.o *.a *~ a.out  app smemlib.o smemlib.a libsmemlib.a  create_memory destroy_memory
```

App.c and memory.c are some other files that I will use on continuing sages of the project.

When I run create_memory I get segmentation fault and smem_init() function does not even prints "Test". I do not get any error when I run smemlib. So, smem_init function works well in the main function of smemlib.c but does not work in the main of create_memory.c. Moreover, when I change the argument of smem_init() in create_memory.c (let us say the argument is 0), no segmentation fault occurs.

Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Your `create_memory` program has two `main` functions, one from `create_memory.c` and one from `smemlib.c`. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: It is curious how it is possible you are even able to link that, because of the multiple main definitions

Comment: I deleted the main function of smemlib.c, nothing changed.

Comment: Also, I did not put the main function in smemlib.h, maybe that is why create_ memory can be linked